# What attribute to name HTML elements for Javascript access

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

What HTML attribute should I use to name HTML elements that I want to address from Javascript. For example if I could use `name`:

```
<table id="some_table">
  <tr>
    <th name="date">Date</td>
    <th name="time">Time</td>
    <th name="name">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I could select them with jQuery like this:

```
$('#some_table th[name=time]')
```

This, however, is invalid, as `name` is not allowed for `td`. `id` must be unique, so I can't use it either. `class` could affect the styling if there is a CSS class `.time`. Maybe something like `data-name`? What is the preferred way?

Comment: There are plenty of ways you can access elements; far too many to list here.

Comment: You don't explain your objective, this might guide the choice. Usually all the tds in a given column have the same purpose, so your attribute seems redundant.

Comment: @Christophe As you say, all the `td`s *in a given column*, so I need a way to address that specific column, therefore I need to give the `td` some attribute with the column name. Note that in the example they already have such an attribute, only it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you don't "need to give the td some attribute with the column name". The standard way would be to get the column index from the column name, then retrieve all tds with this index.

For example if time is the second column (index 1), all the time tds are:

```
getElementById("some_table").rows[i].cells[1]
```

(JavaScript has native methods to traverse tables)

Comment: Where do I get the index from? From a string comparison with the `th`? I find that yucky.

Comment: You can give your th an id if you prefer. Or an attribute. But what is yucky is to repeat it for every row!

Comment: Point taken. I updated the question accordingly. And +1 for referring to table traversing methods.

Comment: So now id works as it is unique. data-name looks fine too, or any custom attribute, for example columnName.

Comment: I think, I'll go with data-value then, as custom attributes require amending the doctype, right?

Comment: No, in html you can use any custom attribute name you want. But data- is more conventional.

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements via their id value, their name, their tagName, their proximity to other elements, any of their values, or even via a selector string. There is no *single* preferred method; it all depends on what you're attempting to do.

In your case, you could select table rows and cells via their index if you like. You could also, as you pointed out, use a data attribute - either approach would render the results you want, a way to access your elements.